How to Upload profileImage to Firestore Database?
i make the register user in firebase
in registerViewcontroller
i have username, email, password and profileImage

below image is Firestore structure
this is what i save user information in firestore database
here is problem
when i select profileimage, username, email, password and tap signup button
problem comes out

the problem is failed to upload profile image to firestore database
and console says
"userImage: <UIImage:0x600003000ea0 anonymous {4032, 3024} renderingMode=automatic(original)>
Firebase Storage 업로드 실패: Object profile_images/rRMJBmF4NlYnlOmVxawxGZqkwzu2.jpg does not exist."
Code Functionality Explanation
User Registration (registerUser)

Uses Firebase Auth to create a user account with an email and password.

Upon successful creation, retrieves the userUID.


Profile Image Upload and Firestore Save (uploadProfileAndSaveUserToFirestore)

Uploads the profile image to Firebase Storage.

Retrieves the download URL after the upload is complete.

Saves the email, username, and profileImageURL in the Firestore users collection under the corresponding user UID.


Firestore User Information Save (saveUserToFirestore)

Stores the username, email, and profileImageURL fields along with the createdAt timestamp in Firestore.

this is my registeruser structure
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct RegisterUserRequest {
    
    let username: String
    let email: String
    let password: String
    
    var userImage: UIImage
    
}

this is my authservice class
func registerUser(request: RegisterUserRequest, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        // 1. Firebase Auth로 사용자 생성
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: request.email, password: request.password) { authResult, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Firebase Auth 사용자 생성 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            guard let userUID = authResult?.user.uid else {
                let uidError = NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "사용자 UID를 가져올 수 없습니다."])
                completion(false, uidError)
                return
            }
            
            // 2. 이미지 업로드와 Firestore 데이터 저장 통합
            self.uploadProfileAndSaveUserToFirestore(userUID: userUID, request: request) { success, error in
                if success {
                    print("회원가입 성공")
                    completion(true, nil)
                } else {
                    print("회원가입 실패: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "알 수 없는 에러")")
                    completion(false, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func uploadProfileAndSaveUserToFirestore(userUID: String, request: RegisterUserRequest, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        // 1. 이미지를 Firebase Storage에 업로드
        guard let imageData = request.userImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {
            completion(false, NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "이미지 데이터를 변환할 수 없습니다."]))
            return
        }
        
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images/\(userUID).jpg")
        storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { metadata, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Firebase Storage 업로드 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false, error)
                return
            }
            
            // 2. 다운로드 URL 가져오기
            storageRef.downloadURL { url, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Firebase Storage 다운로드 URL 가져오기 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    completion(false, error)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let profileImageURL = url?.absoluteString else {
                    completion(false, NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "이미지 URL을 가져올 수 없습니다."]))
                    return
                }
                
                // 3. Firestore에 사용자 정보 저장
                self.saveUserToFirestore(userUID: userUID, username: request.username, email: request.email, profileImageURL: profileImageURL) { success, error in
                    completion(success, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func saveUserToFirestore(userUID: String, username: String, email: String, profileImageURL: String, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        let userData: [String: Any] = [
            "username": username,
            "email": email,
            "profileImageURL": profileImageURL,
            "createdAt": Timestamp()
        ]
        
        db.collection("users").document(userUID).setData(userData) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Firestore 저장 실패: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false, error)
            } else {
                print("Firestore 저장 성공")
                completion(true, nil)
            }
        }
    }

in registerController
below code is PHPickerViewControllerDelegate
extension RegisterController: PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        
        // PHPicker 닫기
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)
        
        // 첫 번째 선택된 아이템 가져오기
        let itemProvider = results.first?.itemProvider
        
        if let itemProvider = itemProvider, itemProvider.canLoadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) {
            // UIImage 불러오기
            itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
                if let image = image as? UIImage { // 불러온 이미지 타입 확인
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        // CustomImageView에 이미지 설정
                        self.profileImage = image
                        self.userPofileView.setImageType(.user(image))
                    }
                } else {
                    print("이미지가 올바르지 않습니다.")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("이미지를 불러올 수 없습니다.")
        }
    }
}

below code is when i tap sign up button for run
in here profileImage is going to userImage
// MARK: - Selectors
    @objc private func didTapSignUp() {
        let username = self.usernameField.text ?? ""
        let email = self.emailField.text ?? ""
        let password = self.passwordField.text ?? ""
        let userImage = profileImage ?? UIImage()
        
        let registerUserRequest = RegisterUserRequest(username: username,
                                                      email: email,
                                                      password: password,
                                                      userImage: userImage)
        
        print("userImage: \(userImage)")
        
        // Check Username
        if !Validator.isValidUsername(for: registerUserRequest.username) {
            AlertManager.showInvalidUsernameAlert(on: self)
            return
        }
        
        // Check Email
        if !Validator.isValidEmail(for: registerUserRequest.email) {
            AlertManager.showInvalidEmailAlert(on: self)
            return
        }
        
        // Check Password
        if !Validator.isValidPassword(for: registerUserRequest.password) {
            AlertManager.showInvalidPasswordAlert(on: self)
            return
        }
        
        AutheService.shared.registerUser(request: registerUserRequest) { wasRegistered, error in
            
            if let error = error {
                AlertManager.showSignInErrorAlert(on: self, with: error)
                return
            }
            
            if wasRegistered {
                if let sceneDelegate = self.view.window?.windowScene?.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
                    sceneDelegate.checkAuthentication()
                }
            } else {
                AlertManager.showSignInErrorAlert(on: self, with: NSError(domain: "", code: 500, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "회원가입 실패"]))
            }
        }
    }


error might be here db.collection("users").document(userUID).setData please try to use setValue instead of setdata

Thanks Jatin  ive been tried to soloved it but the problem was i didnt set the firestore
